# R renv package creates subfolder "staging" - can these be deleted without danger?

Tags: r, staging, renv

I'm using the `renv` package for keeping my R projects identical across computers. I saw that within my R project folder there is a subfolder **renv/staging**. This folder again contains several subfolders named from 1 to XX (in my case 38). Some of these folder contain several thousand files, which causes syncing across my devices often to crash.

I assume these subfolders contain a certain stage of my R project packages and whenever I change sth. (e.g. update a package), a new folder will be created.

**Question is: can I simply delete old folders and just keep the current one (which in my case is empty, though)?**

The renv website unfortunately doesn't tell anything about these staging folder and subfolders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These folders can be safely deleted -- `renv` uses these staging folders when building + installing R packages, with the intention that successfully-installed packages are moved to their final destination in the project library only after all requested packages have been successfully installed.

This is documented partially in https://rstudio.github.io/renv/reference/config.html -- from `renv.config.install.transactional`:

> Perform a transactional install of packages during install and
> restore? When enabled, renv will first install packages into a
> temporary library, and later copy or move those packages back into the
> project library only if all packages were successfully downloaded and
> installed. This can be useful if you'd like to avoid mutating your
> project library if installation of one or more packages fails.
> Defaults to TRUE.

If you aren't a fan of this behavior, you can set this in your `.Rprofile`:

```
options(renv.config.install.transactional = FALSE)
```

Or, in your project's `.Renviron`:

```
RENV_CONFIG_INSTALL_TRANSACTIONAL = FALSE
```

I'll also update the documentation to make it clear that transactional installs make use of the `renv/staging/%i` folder.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Very helpful. One follow-up question: is there also an option to save the project library into the normal R library usually on the home drive of the user? I think currently, if a package in the project has not yet been installed, it is put into the renv/library folder. But woudl it be possible to just save this on the home drive? Reason being: I'm working in a network environment where the project gets synced across several computers and some libraries contain several thousand files which no sync software is able to reliably handle.

Comment: That can be controlled via the `RENV_PATHS_LIBRARY` environment variable -- please see https://rstudio.github.io/renv/reference/paths.html for more information.

Comment: I deleted the library directory where renv maintains a package and now I can’t build the package because ‘it’s missing its DESCRIPTION file’